# TypeScript: Export generic types from function and write them to file

Tags: typescript, types, generator

I've been trying for a while to extract the types from my functions, but I can't get it to work.

We have an (REST)API with many hundreds of endpoints, which we want to call in the frontend typesafe.
The input parameters are no problem, these are defined in the rest api.
Now come the response parameters, here it gets tricky. Because they depend on many classes, which in turn depend on many classes.
Almost all types are generic, e.g. in some modules we use "prisma", which handles database queries and also returns generic types.
But in my IDE (no matter if VSCode or WebStorm) I can look at these types in the preview (tooltip). there they are resolved perfectly.
Since there is certainly no magic leprechaun at work here, it must be possible to extract these types in my code and access them programmatically.

of course i have already dealt with TypeScript - AST etc., but i don't get a usable result here, on the one hand because the types are generic and on the other hand they are imported from many different modules.

any search on this topic is difficult, because it is not about classical handling of TypeScript but about parsing or extracting the types, which should be written into a file afterwards.